# Is there a VB.Net alternative to skip a controlblock without GoTo Next?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop, iteration, goto

So I'm new to VB.Net and still a bit grumpy working without a semicolon but that's fine. 
I'm working my way around. 
Any advice is appreciated !

I got this function:

```
    friend sub find_in_Array(byval string1 as string, byval string_args* as string)

          try

             Dim x_index_count as integer = 10000
             Dim z_index_count as integer = 10000
             Dim array(x_index_count, z_index_count) As String

             for x = o to x_index_count -1

                 dim my_data(y_index_count) as string

                 if not string.isnullorempty(string1) then
                     if not array(x,y).contains(string1) then GoTo LineNext
                 end if

                 ''// Now Following another 10 checks for additional args* given

                 ListfromClass.Add(my_data)

         LineNext:
                 next

         catch ex as exception

            setSmThnToLogFile(ex.Message)

        end try

    end sub
```

The Two-Dimensional Array Axis X and Z are rounded but no overestimated.
And they're generally the reason why I'm asking this question.

Looping through arrays is not the time I want my code to spend with.
Every chance to reduce it is fine with me.

unfortunately Visual Basic doesn't accept this code version :

```
friend sub find_in_Array(byval string1 as string)
      try
         Dim x_index_count as integer = 10000
         Dim z_index_count as integer = 10000
         Dim array(x_index_count, z_index_count) As String

         for x = o to x_index_count -1
             dim my_data(y_index_count) as string

             if not string.isnullorempty(string1) then
                 if not array(x,y).contains(string1) then Next
             end if
         next
     catch ex as exception
        setSmThnToLogFile(ex.Message)
    end try
end sub
```

Because Next can't reach out of the if-condition-block to the for-loop-block.

But I still want to do it.

There's one big argument for this case. To ignore everything because the time difference on recent released pcs might not even be noticeable.
(Around 1 Second). But I'm ignoring this one because

as it is, it just doesnt make sense to process code I don't need it to.

If there's an alternative for the second version of code not involving a GoTo Line ( that's not nearly as much of a devil as many say but still a saying ) I'd be glad to hear.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: You want the [`Continue` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Continue For

How to: Skip to the Next Iteration of a Loop (Visual Basic) [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z6zekeaa(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly where you want your program flow to go to in this case, but a choice of either:

```
Exit For 'Transfers control out of the For Each loop.

Continue For 'Transfers control to the start of the For Each loop.the next one
```

You can find the documentation on these here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx